# I'm using Xcode for c++ programming and study. Why can't I put many separate source files with MAIN function in one project?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, xcode6

I think I can do it in eclipse. 
BTW, every time I make a new C++ file with the system default template.

It has `#include <stdio.h>` instead of `#include <iostream>`

How to fix it?

Comment: Because your project builds one executable, and an executable can only have one `main`. You can have several projects in the same workspace, if you want to keep them in one place.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I put many separate source files with MAIN function in one project?

Because your linker can only allow a single implementation of a function per linking object, but you try to give him multiple `int main` implementations.

Because you did not configure XCode to behave differently, it tries to link all files into one binary object, leading to this conflict.

> I think I can do it in eclipse.

Quite surely not, unless you forgot to add the source files to the list of files that end up in your binary, or you forget to define a binary that links everything together.

Comment: so i need to create a new project for every single task?